# How to get rows from MySQL table with two field to order by?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table in MySQL with fields:

- id - int;
- date - datetime;
- rating - decimal(3,2);

and so on, other fields are not necessary in this selection.
There are about 6000 rows in the table.
I have to get rows from the table that is ordered by rating ASC for the last 6 months and then other rows ordered by id ASC. 
How can I do it?Will it work fast?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this to achieve that:

```
select * 
  from tbl
 order by case 
          when date >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH) then 
               rating 
          else id 
           end ASC;
```

Comment: This won't work. It will sort old values with low `id` values before new values with high `rating` values.

Comment: @Nick Do you know, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all the records from the last 6 months come first in the result, and then worry about ordering by `rating` or `id`. You can do that by ordering on the boolean

```
date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

first, and then on either `rating` or `id` as appropriate. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH DESC,
         CASE WHEN date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH THEN rating
              ELSE id
         END
```